# What to do with output from function returning double pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this dilemma. `fruit` is a struct.

```
fruit** func2create(const int N, const int M)
{
    fruit **arr;
    arr = new fruit*[N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new fruit[M];
    }

    return arr;
}
```

This function returns a pointer pointing to a 2d array, at least that is what I think it does.

Now, having this function, how do I actually make a 2d array using it?

Comment: *"how do I actually make a 2d array using it"* What do you mean? It already returns (more or less) a 2D array.

Comment: Unless you're practicing the use of `new` and `delete` (or writing a custom container or smart pointer), you shouldn't use them at all. Returning a 1D `std::vector` would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Well, I know but this is a function, so i cannot use "arr" that was created inside of it outside of it for further operations, bcs of scope. How to assign this "arr" created by it to some other name in main? And yes, I am using ```new``` and ```delete``` (this is not my choice tho).

Comment: Exactly the same as you'd do with any other function. Compare with `int foo() {int x = 42; return x;}`. How do you use (the copy of) `x` outside of the function? By writing something like `int y = foo();`, then using `y`. And here, you do `fruit **a = func2create(10, 20);`, then use `a` instead of `arr`.

Comment: That's also what I have figured out, but I am not sure about this solution. I am also ordered to code a funciton that will delete my new 2d array. And I have to pass a 2d array as a parameter. I do not know wheather making a funciton ```funcDel(**arr)``` and passing ```**a``` to it, will be viewed as good solution.

Comment: You either make `void funcDel(fruit **arr)` and pass `a`, or make it `func(fruit **&arr)` and also pass `a`. The latter has a benefit of being able to zero `a`, but both are viable.

Comment: In both cases, since the array is a 2D sparse array, you have to also pass in the size of the 1st dimension, since you need to `delete[]` the inner arrays before `delete[]`'ing the outer array.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the notation with double pointers. It is sure to result in a memory leak somewhere since it is not clear who will cleanup the memory. In C++ I would use one of the following methods (using either std::array, or std::vector). Which is also more in line with the C++ core guidelines regarding the use of new/delete (https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines look for anything about pointers and/or new/delete)

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

struct fruit
{
};

// sizes know at compile time then use a function template 
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
auto func2create()
{
    // create initialized array
    std::array<std::array<fruit, M>, N> fruits{};
    return fruits;
}

// for runtime sizes use std::vector
// note I don't use ints (they can have negative values
// I don't want to test for that)
auto func2create(const std::size_t n, const std::size_t m)
{
    // create n rows of m fruits
    std::vector<std::vector<fruit>> fruits(n, std::vector<fruit>(m));
    return fruits;
}

int main()
{
    // compile time allocate fruits
    {
        auto fruits = func2create<4, 4>();
        auto fruit = fruits[1][1];
    }

    // runtime alloacted fruits
    {
        auto fruits = func2create(4ul, 4ul);
        auto fruit = fruits[1][1];
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have read your reply just seconds after running my code for deleting this array. And as you said it has resulted in a memory leak. Unfortunately I have to stick to what my assignment requires of me.

Comment: I appreciate you having to stick with your assignement. Could you ask your teacher if he's aware of the C++ core guidelines for me? It could still be he's just teaching how hard it is to get manual memory managment right :) (Note to teacher : I have almost 30 years of C++ experience)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```cpp
int N = ...;
int M = ...;
fruit** arr = func2create(N, M);

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
        // use arr[i][j] as needed...
    }
}

... 

for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    delete[] arr[i];
}
delete[] arr;
```

Comment: Well it seems to be exactly what I have done now. And it works... well kind of. Delete function does not clear everything for some reason.

Comment: @Nemo Please clarify what you mean by `"Delete function does not clear everything..."`.

Comment: For instance, instead of 0, it "assgins" the value of 4.59135e-41.

Comment: ```i: 2, j: 2, Kind: , Quality: 0, Weight: 0 |
i: 2, j: 3, Kind: 8ĘŮ;ř⌂, Quality: 1004447800, Weight: 4.59135e-41``` top row is cleared correctly, but bottom one was not cleared.

Comment: @Nemo You can't access the memory after it's been `delete`d -- that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Nemo I suspect you misunderstood what `delete` does, which is *not* "clearing" the allocated memory.

Comment: Ok, so how to show that I have deleted it?

Comment: @Nemo you can't show it. Like GM said, accessing the contents of freed memory is undefined behavior. The correct thing to do is not use the memory at all anymore once it has been freed. But clearly you are, hence the bad output, so you need to fix that in your code. But you haven't shown that code yet, so nobody can help you fix it. So please update your original question with more details.